# PHP don't allow format d/m/Y in String date

Tags: php, string, date

I want to validate a String that should be saved as a Date. I want users to give the date in the form in this `format ('d-m-Y)`.
I am using this function to check if an valid date was given:

```
function isDateValid($birthdate)
{
  $date = date('Y-m-d', $birthdate);        

  $stamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date), $date);

  if (!is_numeric($stamp))
     return FALSE;

  //checkdate(month, day, year)
  if ( checkdate(date('n', $stamp), date('d', $stamp), date('Y', $stamp)) )
  {
     return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

This works fine for every entry in this format d-m-y. But when a format like this is given d/m/Y , it still returns true but the date is saved like this m/d/Y in the database.

What can I do to make sure an entry in this format 'd/m/y' is not possible to save in the Database.

Thanks in advance

**Found a solution**

Ok I think I found a solution

```
if(!preg_match('/^(\d\d?)-(\d\d?)-(\d\d\d\d)$/', $birthdate, $matches))
{
  return false;
}
return checkdate($matches[2], $matches[1], $matches[3]);
```

I check if the right pattern was given , after that I check if it is a valid date.
This works fine for me so, thanks!!

Comment: don't ever allow users to insert date as text, couse they might insert strings you can never think of. use some datepicker

Comment: If both month and day values are <= 12, it is simply not possible to determine whether they are in the correct order. They both represent valid dates.

Comment: dont use a string in the database to store the date, use the appropriate date format then it is irrelevant what format the date was entered in. Alternatively just check if the valid year is < 100 if so it is y format not Y formatted

Comment: @k102 Even with a date picker, you cannot rely on user input being in a valid format. You will still need to validate the date in case someone has manipulated the input data.

Comment: @SarahPantry, of course. i just wanted to give a small advice, not a complete solution =)

Comment: The input is saved as an date in the database. "birthdate Type = Date"

$registration->set("birthdate", date('Y-m-d', $birthdate));

Comment: you shouldn't bother users with such trivial things as the format of a date... if they want to use another format, well let them be. Just use the [date_create()](http://nl3.php.net/date_create) function to determine if your user has inputted a valid date string, then format the date yourself using the returned Date object

Comment: @giorgio That really doesn't work. '04-06-2012' can refer to the 4th of June 2012, but also the 6th of April. If you get a string like that, there's no way you can determine which format the user meant.

Comment: @BerryLangerak definitely true, but as DaveRandom mentioned there is no way whatsoever to determine which date someone meant, no matter the format (using / or -). If you want to rule out mistakes like that use a datepicker, as Anigel mentioned. But this is just the problem with days, you'll never know... Maybe a better solution is to use a textual representation of the month (eg. 'January 4 2012'), but offcourse you'd want to let a date picker fill in the month name for your user. And still then, a date picker can be circumvented too

Comment: @giorgio I'm not saying that you shouldn't validate the date, I'm just saying that with an international crowd, it's next to impossible to get it right, unless you separate the fields for day, month and year.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex-pattern like: `*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}*` to check the format